# How to download FederationMetadata xml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory

I got a task to setup ADFS on AWS and integrate it with AWS identity provider (SAML) and for that I  tried to setup following component.

AD CA 
AD DS
AD FS

Everything looks good but when I am going to download FederationMetadata.xml file then instead of giving me xml file it render some text file on IE browser. 
I really do not know what this file contains, Following is the file that is coming on browser.

Can someone help on this. From where i can download this file or this there something I am missing during ADFS setup.

Reference Video :  **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYTN8AAQtrg**

Un8glSDz68b4EHxt4eKf9OvjqMNi5ZEGwqv1GLI/Vg0=N8sA+ttmOeDdNoAvlURBOIgiLkWhVl4fL9sXdzYVTw9xPNqxt476pbE7ouvd5CopcTo/GSnxup1niGg7gWEpa5LbJBuptJMFj4d5ZUM0z9CXgqHqS1+G7+sU2W4vUwkkqmWUypObcMxZBFDaYVUYQHpx/peDN5YkjiYrcRu2c61KVR7zKV8g6ijcXyb5ERQbdIkxPCPIZR+DNd7D0Vpk4G4L5isVFcWKsxeess9cAWHy4KfShnfsSwSRHLT2jiDC13XQRNTlpurVVbRbkal5ag6wylS54B893NjIQYm6+s3LPtA2x6zDAh1pimNh9t4IAwpkcKT6hUB3wVA1G8rU+g==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E-Mail AddressThe e-mail address of the userGiven NameThe given name of the userNameThe unique name of the userUPNThe user principal name (UPN) of the userCommon NameThe common name of the userAD FS 1.x E-Mail AddressThe e-mail address of the user when interoperating with AD FS 1.1 or AD FS 1.0GroupA group that the user is a member ofAD FS 1.x UPNThe UPN of the user when interoperating with AD FS 1.1 or AD FS 1.0RoleA role that the user hasSurnameThe surname of the userPPIDThe private identifier of the userName IDThe SAML name identifier of the userAuthentication time stampUsed to display the time and date that the user was authenticatedAuthentication methodThe method used to authenticate the userDeny only group SIDThe deny-only group SID of the userDeny only primary SIDThe deny-only primary SID of the userDeny only primary group SIDThe deny-only primary group SID of the userGroup SIDThe group SID of the userPrimary group SIDThe primary group SID of the userPrimary SIDThe primary SID of the userWindows account nameThe domain account name of the user in the form of domain\userIs Registered UserUser is registered to use this deviceDevice IdentifierIdentifier of the deviceDevice Registration IdentifierIdentifier for Device RegistrationDevice Registration DisplayNameDisplay name of Device RegistrationDevice OS typeOS type of the deviceDevice OS VersionOS version of the deviceIs Managed DeviceDevice is managed by a management serviceForwarded Client IPIP address of the userClient ApplicationType of the Client ApplicationClient User AgentDevice type the client is using to access the applicationClient IPIP address of the clientEndpoint PathAbsolute Endpoint path which can be used to determine active versus passive clientsProxyDNS name of the federation server proxy that passed the requestApplication IdentifierIdentifier for the Relying PartyApplication policiesApplication policies of the certificateAuthority Key IdentifierThe Authority Key Identifier extension of the certificate that signed an issued certificateBasic ConstraintOne of the basic constraints of the certificateEnhanced Key UsageDescribes one of the enhanced key usages of the certificateIssuerThe name of the certificate authority that issued the X.509 certificateIssuer NameThe distinguished name of the certificate issuerKey UsageOne of the key usages of the certificateNot AfterDate in local time after which a certificate is no longer validNot BeforeThe date in local time on which a certificate becomes validCertificate PoliciesThe policies under which the certificate has been issuedPublic KeyPublic Key of the certificateCertificate Raw DataThe raw data of the certificateSubject Alternative NameOne of the alternative names of the certificateSerial NumberThe serial number of a

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, its was silly question. After downloading google chrome it allowed me to download file in correct format.

Thanks